# Amazon Sagemaker Factorization Machine inconsistent prediction results

Tags: json, protocol-buffers, amazon-sagemaker

Amazon Sagemaker's Factorization Machine model's inference results differ based on input data format. I am receiving different prediction results depending whether the inference data is json or protobuf.

My JSON input data is sparse.
Protobuf RecordIO input data is also sparse.

I have assumed that no matter the input data format, the Factorization Machine's predictions should be stable?

Comment: your assumption is correct. No matter the input data format, the Factorization Machine's predictions should be stable. Could you share more details, number of factors and an example of JSON request?

Comment: @Yury Thanks, but I found out that my RecordIO data was in the wrong format. I was able to fix it using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/cdf-inference.html